# How to add column header to Spark SQL query results without using databricks lib?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, header

How can we add a header to Spark SQL Query results before saving the results in a textfile?

```
val topPriceResultsDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM retail_db.yahoo_stock_orc WHERE open_price > 40 AND high_price > 40 ORDER BY date ASC")

topPriceResultsDF.map(x => x.mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile("/user/sparkuser/myspark/data/output/yahoo_above40_results(comma).csv")
```

It saves only data but I need to add header  like 
(date,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price,volume,adj_price) as well . Please help if anyone has idea !!  I cannot use databricks library.

O/P should be like

```
date,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price,volume,adj_price
1997-07-09,40.75008,45.12504,40.75008,43.99992,37545600,1.83333
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Are you reading from Hive table ?

Comment: Yes from Hive table but it should not create any difference.

Comment: Can you try with this property `sqlContext.setConf("set hive.cli.print.header","true")` Make sure you are using `HiveContext`.

Comment: No header added after setting this property

Answer (score 0):

If you want header for each file:

```
val header: String = ...

df.rdd.map(x => x.mkString(","))
  .mapPartitions(iter => Iterator(header) ++ iter)
  .saveAsTextFile(...)
```

If you want for the first one:

```
df.rdd.map(x => x.mkString(","))
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex { 
    case (0, iter) => Iterator(header) ++ iter
    case (_, iter) => iter }
  .saveAsTextFile(...)
```